# what's a virtual dedicated host?

Tags: website, web, hosting, web-hosting

I understand what's a VPS, and what's a dedicated host.

But what's a virtual dedicated hosting??

Answer (score 3):

A VPS guarantees that you can have the resources that you need at peaks. VDS is where you're guaranteed those resources. For most people doing simple things, they're essentially the same thing. You have a virtual machine running on a server.

If you have a VPS being hosted on an 8 core machine and you're registered for a 1 core VPS. You may share that computer with 10 other people. No one would be running their VPS as 100% CPU usage at all times, so you're essentially sharing resources.

If you have a VDS in the example above. The machine has 8 cores and you would share the computer with up to 8 other Virtual machines (as long as they don't exceed 8 cores in total)

So you see, they're essentially the same thing. VDS is a for sure bet that you're going to have the resources that you're paying for when you need them.

Dedicated host is where you're not virtual and using the actual machines.

Comment: so are you saying a VPS is more secure than VDS ?

Comment: For security, they both use the same virtualization technology. Security is not a real issue from this aspect. (It wouldn't make sense to use two different virtualization technologies cause it would suck to administer.)

Comment: It's really absolutely nothing to do with security. It's all about the resources.